# Why is there no server-side proxy for the OData calls in JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, proxy, odata

I always thought if you made http request to servers, they have to be on the same domain when calling via jquery ajax call? If you look at something like this: http://datajs.codeplex.com. It doesn't have any PHP/.NET proxies on there. How can jquery make async calls to netflix without any server-side?

Answer (score 0):

They use various [cross-domain](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Cross%20Domain%20Requests&referringTitle=Documentation) mechanisms:

- Proxy (they call this "relaying mechanism")
- [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Cross origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control)
- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)